# How to specify custom wakeword in spokestack-android

Tags: android, voice-recognition, voice, spokestack

How can I specify a custom wakeword name (eg "stack overflow" or "party time") in the spokestack-android configuration? I'm looking for something like:

```
SpeechPipeline pipeline = new SpeechPipeline.Builder()
    .setProperty("wakeword", "stack overflow")
//...
    .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: You can train your own wakeword (without writing code, just providing audio samples) with a [Maker subscription](https://www.spokestack.io/pricing#maker). When they're finished training, you can download and [configure the custom wake word](https://www.spokestack.io/docs/android/turnkey-configuration#speech-pipeline) the same way you set up the default wake word.

---

Currently, Spokestack Android only supports wakeword detection via a binary classifier, so we only recognize "Spokestack". In theory, this *could* be done via Android's platform ASR, with the caveat that the user would constantly be interrupted by Google Assistant-style audible dings as the ASR request times out and gets restarted, so it'd only be useful for informal demos, not real apps.

That said, it's theoretically possible, so feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/spokestack/spokestack-android/issues), and it might show up in a future version if we get enough demand for it.